# table view delegate methods not being called in new view controller in storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

in my application i am using storyboards. In the storyboard i have used the default view controller for login and created another view controller name Inventory. In the new view controller i am using a table view. The table is displaying but the delegate and datasource methods are not being called. I have tried many solutions but i dint understand the problem.The code i used is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InventoryViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,     UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

the implementation file is:

```
 #import "InventoryViewController.h"
#import "customCell.h"
@interface InventoryViewController ()

@end

@implementation InventoryViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 110, 320, 350)];
table.delegate = self;
table.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:table];
 [table relaodData];

}
- (IBAction)Logout:(id)sender {
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;  }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSLog(@"hello");
return 5;

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customcell"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:@"customcell"];
}

// Here we use the provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
// Ensure you use a placeholder image otherwise cells will be initialized with no image
cell.item_image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_strip_logo.png"];
cell.type.text = @"electronics";
cell.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my object %d",indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: is "hello" printed in the log when you run the project?

Comment: @Ashu no hello is not printed and the no.of cells is also not 10..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply -`reloadData`: method after setting deledate, datasource and datasource array.

reloadData

Reloads the rows and sections of the receiver.
- (void)reloadData
Discussion

Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on. For efficiency, the table view redisplays only those rows that are visible. It adjusts offsets if the table shrinks as a result of the reload. The table view's delegate or data source calls this method when it wants the table view to completely reload its data. It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates

Go through this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

Comment: i have added that method, still the delegate methods are not being called and an empty table is coming

Comment: @BalaChandra,  update your question latest code and check also custom cell outlet is properly configured/If programmatically then check code.

Comment: Customecell is configured, but even i have specified the number of cells as 10 and in that method i have used nsLog(@"hello") it is also not printed the no.of cells is not 10

Comment: Dude NSLog statement will not execute because you returning before from that function.